# Submitting sitemaps with 2 different websites but the same content

Tags: domains, sitemap

I have two domains running on the same server with the same IP (same content).

For example: the sitemap of `example1.com` represents one website and `method1.com`, `method2.com` represent many pages will come. So can I use only one sitemap for both or make different sitemaps?

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <url>
        <loc>http://xyz.com/</loc>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>1.00</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://abc.com</loc>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.80</priority>
    </url>
```

If I'm working on the second URL it's affecting the homepage also.

Whether I need to create 2nd URL for sitemap or homepage url?

Comment: Why do you want to create a sitemap? If Google are indexing the two websites then a sitemap isn't needed.

Comment: @GeoffJackson-zigojacko: A submitted sitemap can help with reporting. You can easily see how many URLs from the sitemap have been indexed, and consequently if you submit multiple sitemaps for different parts of the site, you can easily see if these sections have been indexed.

Answer (score 3):

If you have two verified sites (verified in Webmaster Tools) means you can have a single sitemap.

> If you have multiple websites, you can simplify the process of creating and submitting Sitemaps by creating one or more Sitemaps that includes URLs for all your verified sites, and saving the Sitemap(s) to a single location. All sites must be verified in Webmaster Tools. You can choose to use:
>
> - A single Sitemap that includes URLs for multiple websites, including sites from different domains. For example, the Sitemap located at http://host1.example.com/sitemap.xml can include URLs for the following sites:
>
>   - http://host1.example.com
>   - http://host2.example.com
>   - http://host3.example.com
>   - http://host1.example1.com
>   - http://host1.example.ch

Source: [Simplify multiple sitemap management](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en)

Comment: Note that the ability to have a single sitemap for multiple domains   is Google-only AFAIK. This is not part of the [Sitemap protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make different sitemaps as you cannot have URLs from different domains within.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: ok but home page url is in frameset and redirecting to another url has many pages and homepage has 1 url

Comment: <url>
    <loc>http://www.example1.com</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.7</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://www.method1.com</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.7</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://www.method2.com</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.7</priority>
</url>

Comment: example.com is home page method1.com is another

Comment: Sitemap protocol : http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html